# SQL Oracle: определить день недели на недельных отрезках

Tags: sql, oracle

Возможно ли как-то более элегантно работать с неделями,
по аналогии с конструкцией:

```
and date = add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
```

но только с неделями, соответственно нужно получить какое число было/будет в `понедельник` и также перемещаться между неделями

пока получилось следующим образом вычесть

```
trunc(sysdate, 'd') - (n*7) + 1
```

Comment: Что именно вам надо сделать? Какую конкретную задачу решаете? Можно пример?

Comment: @SwaD, мне нужно было перемещаться между неделями/понедельниками, искал более элегантное решение по аналогии с функцией add_months, т.е. получать число на понедельник прошлой недели и т.п. по итогу воспользовался конструкцией trunc(sysdate, 'd') - (n*7) + 1,